# How to change the hover background color on a :before element?

Tags: wordpress

Please refer to my project: http://www.livingthelighterlife.com/

Trying to get the hover background colors for the social media section to work. The icons are appearing via a :before tag. I tried adding :before:hover but it is not working.

IN ADDITION: I can't seem to figure out why there are dashes appearing between each. Please help correct this as well!

Any help would be appreciated!

```css
[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 1em;
 width: 1em;
 font-family: "fontello";
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-align: center;

 padding: 5px;
 padding-left: 6px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon-rss:before, .icon-pinterest:before, .icon-twitter:before {
 background: #4a4947;
}

.icon-rss:before:hover, .icon-pinterest:before:hover, .icon-twitter:before:hover {
 background: #f15c58 !important;
}

.icon-facebook:before, .icon-instagram:before, .icon-heart:before {
 background: #f15c58;
}

.icon-facebook:before:hover, .icon-instagram:before:hover, .icon-heart:before:hover {
 background: #4a4947;
}

.icon-rss:before { content: '\e801'; } /* '' */
.icon-facebook:before { content: '\f30c'; } /* '' */
.icon-pinterest:before { content: '\f312'; } /* '' */
.icon-instagram:before { content: '\f32d'; } /* '' */
.icon-twitter:before { content: '\f309'; } /* '' */
.icon-heart:before { content: '\e802'; } /* '' */
```

```html
<span class="icon-rss"></span>
</a>

&nbsp;

<a target="new" href="#">
<span class="icon-facebook"></span>
</a>

&nbsp;

<a target="new" href="#">
<span class="icon-pinterest"></span>
</a>

&nbsp;

<a target="new" href="#">
<span class="icon-instagram"></span>
</a>

&nbsp;

<a target="new" href="#">
<span class="icon-twitter"></span>
</a>

&nbsp;

<a target="new" href="#">
<span class="icon-heart"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the other way around: `.icon-rss:hover:before` and to remove the dashes add `text-decoration: none` to the `a` tag.

Edit: or, in your setup you could also try `a:hover span` to change the background color of `span`.

Comment: Which tag do I add text-decoration: none to?

Comment: the a tag: a { text-decoration: none; }

Comment: Don't think you need the span either, you can simplify it by using <a class="icon-rss"></a> etc.